# How to handle loss of connection in Angular2 with RXJS HTTP when polling

Tags: http, angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I have the following code (simplified for this post) - assume an initial call to `onStart()`.

Running this works fine. If I lose the internet connection I get the `net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED` error (as expected) ***but*** the polling stops.

Clearly I am not handling any errors here as that is where I'm getting stuck. I'm not clear where I handle those errors and how? Do I need to call `startPolling()` again?

I need the polling to continue even if there is no internet connection, so that on re-connection data is updated. Any advice please?

```
onStart() {
    this.startPolling().subscribe(data => {
        // do something with the data
    });
}

startPolling(): Observable<any> {
    return Observable
        .interval(10000)
        .flatMap(() => this.getData());
}

getData() {
    var url = `http://someurl.com/api`;
    return this.http.get(url)
        .map(response => {
            return response.json();
        });
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know the error happens because of `this.http.get(url)` then you can add `catch()` operator that lets you subscribe to another Observable instead of the source Observable that sent an `error` notification.

```
getData() {
    var url = `http://someurl.com/api`;
    return this.http.get(url)
        .catch(err => Observable.empty())
        .map(response => {
            return response.json();
        });
}
```

This will simply ignore the error and won't emit anything.

Comment: Thanks Martin I'll give that a go.

Comment: Worked a treat thank you. Think I need to swot up a little on observables..